# Making pictures NOT move in sync in Holoviews

Tags: python, holoviews

Is there a way to force two graphs in same layout to unlink.

- **Here's an [example](http://holoviews.org/getting_started/Introduction.html):** Under headline `'Compositional Layouts'`, the two pictures are not synced, but under headline `'Compositional Overlays'` the pictures are synced.

The code in those two seems very much same, so I'm looking for a way to unlink the latter images so that I can move only the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the bokeh backend?  Try `%%opts Layout [shared_axes=False]` or `.opts(plot=dict(shared_axes=False))`